# Wait for batch file Java

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I have a batch file which is part of an installer I have made. I would like the file to execute then when the file has finished to continue with the rest of the installation (which depends on the output of the batch file so they cannot be done in parallel). I am using getRuntime().exec() to run the batch file and then using process.waitFor() to wait for completion. When using the "/C" option process.waitFor() fires immediately even though the command is still running. When using the "/K" option process.waitFor() never returns, even when I have exit at the bottom of the file to close the window.

Is there another way to wait for a program to finish executing or will I have to do something hacky with the batch file to signal the application somehow that it is complete?

Comment: Do you have `START` in the command line? If so, remove it.

Comment: @EJP I did, and removing it has fixed it. Thank you :)